# SQL Server Job system silently fails

Tags: sql-server, scheduling

We run numerous scheduled jobs using MS SQL 2005 job scheduler.

Over the past few weeks, we've been witnessing that a running job will simply **STOP** and will not record any history in the Log File Viewer.

What appears to be happening is that the server will start a job and record these steps into msdb.  At a random step during a job, the server will stop running the job and it records no error.  This silent failure prevents a "Step 0" record from being created and we won't see anything in the Log File Viewer.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Can you give more details about the steps?

Comment: Afraid I cannot.  It is random and we haven't experienced this in several weeks.  I thought server load was contributing to this, but cannot find a repeatable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to get some more details on what the job is doing:

In SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Connect to the instance
2. Expand SQL Server Agent
3. Expand Jobs
4. Right-click on the job and view properties
5. In the Advanced window, specify an output file
6. Run the job and post the file contents (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Never experienced this behavior.

Is this any running job under SQL Agent or a particular one?   Anything remarkable in the SQL log or application or system event logs? You can see the recorded steps in msdb?
What about starting Profiler, starting your job and examining the Profiler output?

Answer (score 0):

I always always always (get the idea :) ) ...always direct the output of each step of every job to a text file somewhere on the server. This is ideal for these kind of scenarios.

step 1 I set for the output file to overwrite
and every subsequent step I step to append to that same file.

...and I ensure this is done on each and every job to a standard output location. There is stuff that is outputted that sometimes doesnt usually make it into job history but will into a text file.